# Using a materialized view log to allow a fast refresh materialized view when materialized via based on a view

Tags: oracle, logging, materialized-views

I have a materialized view mv_test based on a view v_test based on a single table t_test. I have created a materialized view log on the table t_test:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON t_test
WITH ROWID
INCLUDING NEW VALUES
```

but when trying to create a log on the materialized view mv_test I get an error saying table does not exist. Am I allowed to do what I describe above?

Comment: What do you mean "create a log on the materialized view mv_test"? Please post the actual code you are using, and any error messages you are receiving.

Comment: Does t_test table exists in that schema?